# Using Enigmail encryption on mutiple devices

Tags: encryption, thunderbird, enigmail

So I'm relatively new to email encryption and thought I would start out using thunderbird + enigmail to get me started. I've managed to set it up and work with it properly but I'm not sure what to do for me next situation:

I have mutiple computers that I use to access the same email account.
I currently have one key-pair generated for that mail account on computer A
Now I also want to use that same mail account on computer B

How can I have encryption work and have one public key that people can use to communicate with me?

Do I export my private key and import it into my mail client on computer B?
Do I generate a new key-pair for each device? If so how do I prevent encumbiring people with keeping mutiple key pairs so they can decrypt my mail depending on the device I'm using?

Any form of help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: There should be only one key pair for each account. Hence, you would export the keys and import them on the other device.

Answer (score 0):

"*How can I have encryption work and have one public key that people can use to communicate with me? Do I export my private key and import it into my mail client on computer B?*"

Yes. Like you & DragonLord said. One public key only has one private key, if you want to decrypt your messages on a (any) device, you need the private key on that device too.